# Multiple NamedPipeServerStreams in same process

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

I have made a first implementation of a process that keeps two different `NamedPipeServerStream`s running and receiving messages on both. I'm wondering if there is a way to react on a task directly when it is completed, instead of using a `Thread.Sleep` in this case. The code below works fine, I just feel like it could be more efficient, reacting to when a task completes instead of polling with an interval, but I can't figure out how.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serverA = new NamedPipeServerStream("A", PipeDirection.InOut);
    var readerA = new StreamReader(serverA);
    var writerA = new StreamWriter(serverA);
    var serverB = new NamedPipeServerStream("B", PipeDirection.InOut);
    var readerB = new StreamReader(serverB);
    var writerB = new StreamWriter(serverB);

    Task taskA = serverA.WaitForConnectionAsync();
    Task taskB = serverB.WaitForConnectionAsynC();

    while(true)
    {
        if (taskA.IsCompleted)
        {
            string? requestText = readerA.ReadLine(); // Read a request
            ... // Handle request
            writerA.WriteLine("My response"); // Write a response
            writerA.Flush();
            serverA.Disconnect(); // Disconnect the current pipe
            taskA = serverA.WaitForConnectionAsync(); // Restart taskA to listen for more requests
        }
        else if (taskB.IsCompleted)
        {
            string? requestText = readerB.ReadLine(); // Read a request
            ... // Handle request
            writerB.WriteLine("My response"); // Write a response
            writerB.Flush();
            serverB.Disconnect(); // Disconnect the current pipe
            taskB = serverB.WaitForConnectionAsync(); // Restart taskB to listen for more requests
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // 100 milliseconds is actually quite a long time, too long, but I also don't want to waste CPU cycles by polling too frequently.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a semaphore like WaitOne : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=net-7.0

Comment: But WaitOne hangs the thread. If I want to listen to two different channels, I cannot hang the thread - messages could arrive at any time in any order on any channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Task.WaitAny and I'm now using it instead of Thread.Sleep in order to react immediately when a task completes.

```
else
{
    Task.WaitAny(taskA, taskB); // Wait for either task to complete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Async Events like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static NamedPipeServerStream serverA = null;
        static StreamReader readerA = null;
        static StreamWriter writerA = null;

        static NamedPipeServerStream serverB = null;
        static StreamReader readerB = null;
        static StreamWriter writerB = null;
        static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        public class State
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        }
 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            serverA = new NamedPipeServerStream("A", PipeDirection.InOut);
            readerA = new StreamReader(serverA);
            writerA = new StreamWriter(serverA);
            serverB = new NamedPipeServerStream("B", PipeDirection.InOut);
            readerB = new StreamReader(serverB);
            writerB = new StreamWriter(serverB);

            State stateA = new State() { name = "A" };
            serverA.BeginWaitForConnection(ConnectCallback, stateA);

            State stateB = new State() { name = "B" };
            serverB.BeginWaitForConnection(ConnectCallback, stateB);
            //wait forever, block so program doesn't exit
            autoEvent.WaitOne();
        }
        public static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            State state = ar.AsyncState as State;
            switch (state.name)
            {
                case "A":
                    serverA.BeginRead(state.buffer, 0, 1024, ReadAsyncCallback, state);
                    break;

                case "B":
                    serverB.BeginRead(state.buffer, 0, 1024, ReadAsyncCallback, state);
                    break;
            }

        }
        public static void ReadAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            State state = ar.AsyncState as State;
            string? requestText = "";
            switch (state.name)
            {
                case "A" :
                   requestText = readerA.ReadLine(); // Read a request
                   // Handle request
                   writerA.WriteLine("My response"); // Write a response
                   writerA.Flush();
                   break;

                case "B" :
          
                   requestText = readerB.ReadLine(); // Read a request
                   // Handle request
                   writerB.WriteLine("My response"); // Write a response
                   writerB.Flush();
                   break;
            }

        }
    }

 
}
```