# Using a Named Pipe as a signal from a PowerShell script to a C# Form. Can't get it to work

Tags: c#, powershell, semaphore, named-pipes

I have a PowerShell script that is supposed to install and configure stuff on a machines. Since the script is running under Local System it is completely invisible for the local user and then I thought of creating a small Windows Form in C# that can tell the user what is going on and then close it when the script is finished.
My idea is to use a named pipe as a "semaphore" for this and the order of events would be something like:

1. The PowerShell script starts, creates the pipe, starts the exe and
   then continues with the installation tasks in the script.
2. When the exe starts it checks if the named pipe exists and if it does it shows the
   Form. It regulary checks if the pipe still exists and when it doesn't
   it closes the form and kills itself.
3. When PowerShell is done with the script it disposes the named pipe
   which kills the form and the exe (as described in 2).

I don't know how many different code variants I have now tried but I just can't get it to work.
In the C# code I start with a NamedPipeClientStream.Connect() which works if the pipe exists  and the code continues and shows the Form. When I then would like to see if the pipe has been closed by the server or not I use NamedPipeClientStream.IsConnected but this allways returns 'true' even if I have disposed the Named Pipe from PowerShell. So my form never closes and this drives me crazy....!

At the moment my code looks something like below, but I have kind of lost myself in all the modifications and rearrangements I have tried.  (Perhaps I don't have to point out that I'm not a skilled software developer).

PowerShell:

```
$pipeName = "InstallationRunning"
$pipe = New-Object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream($pipeName, [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::InOut)

# Start the Windows Forms application
Start-Process -FilePath "InstallForm.exe"

# PowerShell does installation tasks

# Close the pipe and exit the application
$pipe.Dispose()
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace InstallForm
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static NamedPipeClientStream PipeClient;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            string pipeName = "InstallationRunning";
            PipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut);
            if (CheckForPipe())
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            else
            {
                // Pipe doesn't exist or connection failed, exit the application
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        private static bool CheckForPipe()
        {
            try
            {
                pipeClient.Connect(500);
                return true; // Pipe exists
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false; // Pipe doesn't exist or connection failed
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool pipeExists = true; // Assume pipe exists initially
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _ = Task.Run(() => CheckPipePeriodically());
        }

        private void CheckPipePeriodically()
        {
            while (pipeExists)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!Program.PipeClient.IsConnected)
                    {
                        pipeExists = false;
                        CloseFormAndExit();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Pipe is disposed or connection failed
                    //pipeExists = false;
                    //CloseFormAndExit();
                    //return;
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // Wait for 1 second before trying again
            }
        }

        private void CloseFormAndExit()
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke(new Action(CloseFormAndExit));
                return;
            }

            Close(); // Close the form
            Environment.Exit(0); // Exit the application
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone who can help me in the right direction here?
Perhaps the whole idea with using a Pipe as a semaphore (I'm not transfering any data in it) is stupid and this could be done in a more clever way?

Comment: why do you need to have a C# app calling a script ? im 99% sure all can be done in the C# app side (or viceversa).

Comment: It's actually the PowerShell script that calls the C#.

Comment: also that C# con is non interactive. is it just to show script progress correct ?

Comment: Yes. I'm thinking of a static Form with just a message (Label) and a PictureBox saying that the installation is ongoing.

Comment: Regarding combining everything I have the PS script that manages a rather complex installation and configuration and I have a good "script engine" to push this PS script out to users. My problem is that the script will be completely invisible for the user (since it's running under Local System) but I know how to start an exe under "logged on user" from the PS script. That's why I started to think of a compiled Form in C#.

Comment: If this is just to show script progress in a form, then you could just wrap your Start-Process in a variable assignment then stop the form process when you don't need it anymore... A lot simpler. Also, I have a project mixing C# and Powershell (So urn Handler I made to execute Powershell from a web link) and I think I faced some problem with pipes too. The statement I ended up using that worked was : ` var isPipeRunning = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\.\pipe\").Contains($"\\\\.\\pipe\\{pipename}");` (pipename being a variable).

Comment: you can discard all the code and start from the scratch :) the only thing you need to consider is this section: # PowerShell does installation tasks and since the answer has just a comment i dont know if it can be measured to show a progress indicator. Can you share some code on the missing section ?

Comment: Ouch, a sleepless night for nothing...   :/
One of the reasons to why I started with the named Pipe was that I hoped that if my PS script for some reason got killed the pipe would close and so would the Form. I don't know if that's how pipes work however.
So Ideally I would like to have a solution which can handle unexpected events. But I could probably add a timer with a reasonable long time to your suggestion Sage.

Comment: Regarding the missing section in the PS, it's a lot of:

Start-Process $env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i `"$MSI_Installation_Path\ComponentA.msi`" /qb" -Wait;

Write-Host "Installing ComponentA"

Start-Process $env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i `"$MSI_Installation_Path\ComponentB.msi`" /qb" -Wait;

Write-Host "Installing ComponentB"

Then some registry manipulation, environment variables settings, font installation etc. It also branches depending on if it's a Server och Workstation.

Comment: You should use Async methods similar to following :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76634522/multiple-namedpipeserverstreams-in-same-process/76913058#76913058

Comment: @jdweng there is NO NEED TO USE AN EXTERNAL APP ! it can be accomplished 100% with PS

Comment: @jmvcollaborator : Yes.  PS is written in Net/Core library and any c# code can be converted to PS.  This posting has both c# and powershell tags.  My link is not an external app.

Comment: @SagePourpre, your Directory.GetFiles approach did solve my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Pure powershell :) You can take this script as reference, feel free to give it a try. Of course the time passed is simulated sleeping the thread.But, you will see how you can simple show progress and steps done. Hope it helps.

```
$TotalItems=3 # here im assuming there are 3 installation steps
$CurrentItem=1
$PercentComplete = 0

Write-Progress -Activity "Preinstallation in Progress" -Status "$PercentComplete% Complete:" -PercentComplete $PercentComplete
$CurrentItem++
$PercentComplete = [int](($CurrentItem / $TotalItems) * 100)
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000

Write-Host "Preinstall complete" 

Write-Progress -Activity "Installation in Progress" -Status "$PercentComplete% Complete:" -PercentComplete $PercentComplete
$CurrentItem++
$PercentComplete = [int](($CurrentItem / $TotalItems) * 100)
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000

Write-Host "Install complete"

Write-Progress -Activity "Postinstallation in Progress" -Status "$PercentComplete% Complete:" -PercentComplete $PercentComplete
$CurrentItem++
$PercentComplete = [int](($CurrentItem / $TotalItems) * 100)
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000
Write-Host "PostInstall complete"

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10000
```

Comment: Nice with a progress bar! But since the script is not running under the logged on user nor the progress bar or the Write-Host will be visible.

Comment: What does this have to do with named pipes?

Comment: what does a distribution installation bringing up a .net app which does nothing ?